# How to make property description attribute visible in IntelliSense?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Giving this property:

```
 public class Data
 {
    
    [Description("DESCRIPTION"), DefaultValue("")]
    public string DESCX1{ get; set; }
  }
  Data data= new Data();
```

I use DESCX1 because it will be easier for me to make some type mappings by property name, but I prefer a friendly name to know which property use in the MVC View.

If I type `data.` how can I make the description visible in Visual Studio 2015 IntelliSense?

Comment: `DESCX1` is your property name so that will show up as it should be. You can make extra info show up when you hover the property with xml comments

Comment: Before asking this question, I would really, really ask myself if its not better to name variables and properties in a way so that I can read them months from now and know what they are for, regardless of any "Description" or comment surrounding them.

Comment: Thank you @Adimeus I understand that position and I agree with it. I just would simplificate the names for earn time in type mapping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. IntelliSense is not designed to deal with this attribute. On the other hand, this attribute was meant to be used by VS Designers.
Things you should do,

1. Give a relevant name to your properties...in this case `Description`
2. Use summary comments...

   ```
   /// <summary>
   /// Description
   /// </summary>
   public string Description{ get; set; }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at something like this?

[XML Documentation Comments (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio Provide IntelliSense for summary using triple forward slash (///). it will add summary tag above method.
best commenting tool in visual studio is GhostDoc. In this tool you can add signature, commenting with input parameter and it will create short description base on your name. [Click Here for GhostDoc](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/46A20578-F0D5-4B1E-B55D-F001A6345748)